# Swagger UI try it out internally in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, swagger

i have deployed swagger UI on Kubernetes. now it's not sending a request to internal service of Kubernetes when clicking on the `Try it out` button.

Since all service running locally in Kubernetes we have to use `HTTP` but my swagger UI is on `HTTPS` so getting mixed content error also.

is there any way we can invoke internal service using swagger UI running inside Kubernetes.

this is my demo swagger.yaml :

```
openapi: 3.0.1
servers:
  - url: '{scheme}://test-service'
    variables:
      scheme:
        description: 'The Data Set API is accessible via https and http'
        enum:
          - 'https'
          - 'http'
        default: 'https'
info:
  description: >-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would rather suggest using ingress and add further rule with `https` domain.

ingress :

```
 apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: swagger-staging
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: swagger-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /test-service(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: service-1
          servicePort: 80
      - path: service-2(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: service-2
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /service-3(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: service-3
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /service-4(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: service-4
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /service-5(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: service-5
          servicePort: 80
```

note : if you will try updating ingress with https and later try with port-forward it will not work and same give error of browser mixed content .

Comment: for now workaround i have used same rule and updated ingress using https,

Answer (score 0):

You can use [port-forwarding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/):

```
kubectl -n <namespace> port-forward svc/<your-swagger-service> <localhost-port>:<swagger-port-in-your-svc>
```

And then go to `localhost:<localhost-port>`

Another way to that is using [internal load balancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) there's some options depends on your cloud provider.

Comment: There's also support for internal load balancer https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/ at least for several cloud providers. Have you tried that?

Comment: May be you can try the internal load balancer first. I've tried it once.
Which one you're referring this to `sorry, cant upvote also it's helpful somewhat.`

Comment: due to low reputation can't upvote your answer. as it's 13 reputation there so. thankyou so much for help and taking time out for reply.